# FAQ displaying style in JavaScript

Tags: php, html, javascript

I have implemented the following JavaScript in my FAQ page:

```
var Spry;
if (!Spry) Spry = {};
if (!Spry.Widget) Spry.Widget = {};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel = function(element, opts)
{   
    this.init(element);

    Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.setOptions(this, opts);

    this.attachBehaviors();
};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.prototype.init = function(element)
{

    this.element = this.getElement(element);
    this.focusElement = null;
    this.hoverClass = "CollapsiblePanelTabHover";
    this.openClass = "CollapsiblePanelOpen";
    this.closedClass = "CollapsiblePanelClosed";
    this.focusedClass = "CollapsiblePanelFocused";
    this.enableAnimation = true;
    this.enableKeyboardNavigation = true;
    this.animator = null;
    this.hasFocus = false;
    this.contentIsOpen = true;
};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.prototype.getElement = function(ele)
{
    if (ele && typeof ele == "string")
        return document.getElementById(ele);
    return ele;
};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.prototype.addClassName = function(ele, className)
{
    if (!ele || !className || (ele.className && ele.className.search(new RegExp("\\b" + className + "\\b")) != -1))
        return;
    ele.className += (ele.className ? " " : "") + className;
};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.prototype.removeClassName = function(ele, className)
{
    if (!ele || !className || (ele.className && ele.className.search(new RegExp("\\b" + className + "\\b")) == -1))
        return;
    ele.className = ele.className.replace(new RegExp("\\s*\\b" + className + "\\b", "g"), "");
};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.prototype.hasClassName = function(ele, className)
{
    if (!ele || !className || !ele.className || ele.className.search(new RegExp("\\b" + className + "\\b")) == -1)
        return false;
    return true;
};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.prototype.setDisplay = function(ele, display)
{
    if( ele )
        ele.style.display = display;
};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.setOptions = function(obj, optionsObj, ignoreUndefinedProps)
{
    if (!optionsObj)
        return;
    for (var optionName in optionsObj)
    {
        if (ignoreUndefinedProps && optionsObj[optionName] == undefined)
            continue;
        obj[optionName] = optionsObj[optionName];
    }
};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.prototype.onTabMouseOver = function()
{
    this.addClassName(this.getTab(), this.hoverClass);
};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.prototype.onTabMouseOut = function()
{
    this.removeClassName(this.getTab(), this.hoverClass);
};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.prototype.open = function()
{

    this.contentIsOpen = true;
    if (this.enableAnimation)
    {
        if (this.animator)
            this.animator.stop();
        this.animator = new Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.PanelAnimator(this, true);
        this.animator.start();


    }
    else
        this.setDisplay(this.getContent(), "block");

    this.removeClassName(this.element, this.closedClass);

    this.addClassName(this.element, this.openClass);

};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.prototype.close = function()
{

    this.contentIsOpen = false;
    if (this.enableAnimation)
    {
        if (this.animator)
            this.animator.stop();
        this.animator = new Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.PanelAnimator(this, false);

        this.animator.start();
    }
    else
        this.setDisplay(this.getContent(), "none");

    this.removeClassName(this.element, this.openClass);

    this.addClassName(this.element, this.closedClass);
};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.prototype.onTabClick = function()
{
    if (this.isOpen())
        this.close();

else
     this.open();
     this.focus();

};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.prototype.onFocus = function(e)
{
    this.hasFocus = true;
    this.addClassName(this.element, this.focusedClass);
};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.prototype.onBlur = function(e)
{
    this.hasFocus = false;
    this.removeClassName(this.element, this.focusedClass);
};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.ENTER_KEY = 13;
Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.SPACE_KEY = 32;

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.prototype.onKeyDown = function(e)
{
    var key = e.keyCode;
    if (!this.hasFocus || (key != Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.ENTER_KEY && key != Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.SPACE_KEY))
        return true;

    if (this.isOpen())
        this.close();
    else
        this.open();

    if (e.stopPropagation)
        e.stopPropagation();
    if (e.preventDefault)
        e.preventDefault();

    return false;
};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.prototype.attachPanelHandlers = function()
{
    var tab = this.getTab();
    if (!tab)
        return;

    var self = this;
    Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.addEventListener(tab, "click", function(e) { return self.onTabClick(); }, false);
    Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.addEventListener(tab, "mouseover", function(e) { return self.onTabMouseOver(); }, false);
    Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.addEventListener(tab, "mouseout", function(e) { return self.onTabMouseOut(); }, false);

    if (this.enableKeyboardNavigation)
    {
        // XXX: IE doesn't allow the setting of tabindex dynamically. This means we can't
        // rely on adding the tabindex attribute if it is missing to enable keyboard navigation
        // by default.

        // Find the first element within the tab container that has a tabindex or the first
        // anchor tag.

        var tabIndexEle = null;
        var tabAnchorEle = null;

        this.preorderTraversal(tab, function(node) {
            if (node.nodeType == 1 /* NODE.ELEMENT_NODE */)
            {
                var tabIndexAttr = tab.attributes.getNamedItem("tabindex");
                if (tabIndexAttr)
                {
                    tabIndexEle = node;
                    return true;
                }
                if (!tabAnchorEle && node.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "a")
                    tabAnchorEle = node;
            }
            return false;
        });

        if (tabIndexEle)
            this.focusElement = tabIndexEle;
        else if (tabAnchorEle)
            this.focusElement = tabAnchorEle;

        if (this.focusElement)
        {
            Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.addEventListener(this.focusElement, "focus", function(e) { return self.onFocus(e); }, false);
            Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.addEventListener(this.focusElement, "blur", function(e) { return self.onBlur(e); }, false);
            Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.addEventListener(this.focusElement, "keydown", function(e) { return self.onKeyDown(e); }, false);
        }
    }
};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.addEventListener = function(element, eventType, handler, capture)
{
    try
    {
        if (element.addEventListener)
            element.addEventListener(eventType, handler, capture);
        else if (element.attachEvent)
            element.attachEvent("on" + eventType, handler);
    }
    catch (e) {}
};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.prototype.preorderTraversal = function(root, func)
{
    var stopTraversal = false;
    if (root)
    {
        stopTraversal = func(root);
        if (root.hasChildNodes())
        {
            var child = root.firstChild;
            while (!stopTraversal && child)
            {
                stopTraversal = this.preorderTraversal(child, func);
                try { child = child.nextSibling; } catch (e) { child = null; }
            }
        }
    }
    return stopTraversal;
};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.prototype.attachBehaviors = function()
{
    var panel = this.element;
    var tab = this.getTab();
    var content = this.getContent();

    if (this.contentIsOpen || this.hasClassName(panel, this.openClass))
    {
        this.removeClassName(panel, this.closedClass);
        this.setDisplay(content, "block");
        this.contentIsOpen = true;
    }
    else
    {
        this.removeClassName(panel, this.openClass);
        this.addClassName(panel, this.closedClass);
        this.setDisplay(content, "none");
        this.contentIsOpen = false;
    }

    this.attachPanelHandlers();
};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.prototype.getTab = function()
{
    return this.getElementChildren(this.element)[0];
};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.prototype.getContent = function()
{
    return this.getElementChildren(this.element)[1];
};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.prototype.isOpen = function()
{
    return this.contentIsOpen;
};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.prototype.getElementChildren = function(element)
{
    var children = [];
    var child = element.firstChild;
    while (child)
    {
        if (child.nodeType == 1 /* Node.ELEMENT_NODE */)
            children.push(child);
        child = child.nextSibling;
    }
    return children;
};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.prototype.focus = function()
{
    if (this.focusElement && this.focusElement.focus)
        this.focusElement.focus();
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.PanelAnimator = function(panel, doOpen, opts)
{
    this.timer = null;
    this.interval = 0;
    this.stepCount = 0;

    this.fps = 0;
    this.steps = 10;
    this.duration = 500;
    this.onComplete = null;

    this.panel = panel;
    this.content = panel.getContent();
    this.panelData = [];
    this.doOpen = doOpen;

    Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.setOptions(this, opts);


    // If caller specified speed in terms of frames per second,
    // convert them into steps.

    if (this.fps > 0)
    {
        this.interval = Math.floor(1000 / this.fps);
        this.steps = parseInt((this.duration + (this.interval - 1)) / this.interval);
    }
    else if (this.steps > 0)
        this.interval = this.duration / this.steps;

    var c = this.content;

    var curHeight = c.offsetHeight ? c.offsetHeight : 0;

    if (doOpen && c.style.display == "none")
        this.fromHeight = 0;
    else
        this.fromHeight = curHeight;

    if (!doOpen)
        this.toHeight = 0;
    else
    {
        if (c.style.display == "none")
        {
            // The content area is not displayed so in order to calculate the extent
            // of the content inside it, we have to set its display to block.

            c.style.visibility = "hidden";
            c.style.display = "block";
        }

        // Unfortunately in Mozilla/Firefox, fetching the offsetHeight seems to cause
        // the browser to synchronously re-layout and re-display content on the page,
        // so we see a brief flash of content that is *after* the panel being positioned
        // where it should when the panel is fully expanded. To get around this, we
        // temporarily position the content area of the panel absolutely off-screen.
        // This has the effect of taking the content out-of-flow, so nothing shifts around.

        // var oldPos = c.style.position;
        // var oldLeft = c.style.left;
        // c.style.position = "absolute";
        // c.style.left = "-2000em";

        // Clear the height property so we can calculate
        // the full height of the content we are going to show.
        c.style.height = "";
        this.toHeight = c.offsetHeight;

        // Now restore the position and offset to what it was!
        // c.style.position = oldPos;
        // c.style.left = oldLeft;
    }

    this.increment = (this.toHeight - this.fromHeight) / this.steps;
    this.overflow = c.style.overflow;

    c.style.height = this.fromHeight + "px";
    c.style.visibility = "visible";
    c.style.overflow = "hidden";
    c.style.display = "block";
};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.PanelAnimator.prototype.start = function()
{
    var self = this;
    this.timer = setTimeout(function() { self.stepAnimation(); }, this.interval);
};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.PanelAnimator.prototype.stop = function()
{
    if (this.timer)
    {
        clearTimeout(this.timer);

        // If we're killing the timer, restore the overflow
        // properties on the panels we were animating!

        if (this.stepCount < this.steps)
            this.content.style.overflow = this.overflow;
    }

    this.timer = null;
};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.PanelAnimator.prototype.stepAnimation = function()
{
    ++this.stepCount;

    this.animate();

    if (this.stepCount < this.steps)
        this.start();
    else if (this.onComplete)
        this.onComplete();
};

Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.PanelAnimator.prototype.animate = function()
{
    if (this.stepCount >= this.steps)
    {
        if (!this.doOpen)
            this.content.style.display = "none";
        this.content.style.overflow = this.overflow;
        this.content.style.height = this.toHeight + "px";
    }
    else
    {
        this.fromHeight += this.increment;
        this.content.style.height = this.fromHeight + "px";
    }
};
```

My problem is that I want to close all other row when I click on any one.

Comment: u won the longest question in the site

Comment: What did you try to solve your problem, and why didn't it work?

Comment: Too much code to look at in one piece for the average joe, try breaking it up into pieces and having a little more actual question asking!

Answer (score 0):

change the "Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.prototype.**onBlur**" section for this:

```
Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.prototype.onBlur = function(e)
{
    this.contentIsOpen = false;
    if (this.enableAnimation)
    {
        if (this.animator)
            this.animator.stop();
        this.animator = new Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.PanelAnimator(this, false, { duration: this.duration, fps: this.fps, transition: this.transition });
        this.animator.start();
    }

    this.removeClassName(this.element, this.openClass);
    this.addClassName(this.element, this.closedClass);
};
```